# Can we add any value in rating count in aggregate rating schema code

Tags: html, seo

one of my competitor website had rating count of 13522, while other had 1950.
i have no idea how they got these numbers. Can we add any number or is there any logic behind it?

Please find below code:

"aggregateRating": {
"@type": "AggregateRating",
"ratingValue": "4.8",
"ratingCount": "15"
}

```
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "4.8",
    "ratingCount": "15122"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The **ratingCount** property declares the total number of reviews. **ratingValue** is the average rating of this total number of reviews. That data should correspond to the real numbers. Otherwise, it is a manipulation, which sooner or later will be punished.

Comment: ok agreed. Can you tell me a way to get real numbers?

Comment: I need an example to be more specific. On the page itself, where the reviews are visible, their actual number can be seen and, accordingly, their average rating can be seen or calculated based on the available data.